# Hard color changes in baking result. Looking for the cause

Tags: texture-baking

I have this cycles scene

[image: scene rendered in cycles]

but when I bake the couch using the settings shown in the screenshot, I get this [bake result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fetqt.jpg), and this is what it looks like when applied to the mesh

[image: bake settings]
[image: bake texture applied on mesh]

What happened? Have I stumbled upon a bug, or is it a misconfiguration? Blend is too big to upload here, but I can try to pare it down to fit blend-exchange if required.

I was expecting that horizontal line that splits light with dark red to not be there (in fact I expect the whole couch to be of a uniform color closer to the light part)

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what result you are expecting? Also, please upload *all* images to imgur using the editor's image functionality. A screenshot of your baking panel would also be helpful.

Comment: I think the baked image removes from the clarity of the question, making it too image-heavy. I edited the question to clarify what I am expecting.

Comment: So combinded baking is intended? Try to bake "diffuse" with only "color" ("direct" and "indirect" should be disabled).

Comment: It could be a texture coordinate mapping problem. Try to change the couch's origin to the lowest object vertex Z position. (the bright red seems to start where the origin is)

Comment: Changing origin seems to correct the issue, I wonder why though. Haven't tried baking diffuse only yet.